# How would you tellraw a player on low health?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to create a mechanic that displays a "(Player)'s life is in danger!" When low on health. This is my main command:

```
 tellraw @a[scores={hp2=1..1},gamemode=survival] {"text":"","color":"red","extra":[{"selector":"@p"},{"text":"'s life is in danger!"}]}
```

However, because the player fits the criteria (and continues to), the command just spams the chat.

Answer (score 1):

You can use tags for this. Tag the player and add `tag=!someTag` to your selector to stop the command from executing. The setup should look like this:

(Repeating command block)

```
/tellraw @a[tag=!someTag,scores={hp2=1},gamemode=survival] {"text":"","color":"red","extra":[{"selector":"@p"},{"text":"'s life is in danger!"}]}
```

(Chain command block)

```
/tag @a[tag=!someTag,scores={hp2=1},gamemode=survival] add someTag
```

(Chain command block)

```
/tag @a[tag=someTag,scores={hp2=2..}] remove someTag
```

Not sure why you are using 1..1 as that can only be 1. I changed the values so the text is displayed if hp2 is 1 and the tag will be removed when hp2 is 2 or more.

Comment: Awesome, this worked! Would I use this same format to display a message when someone kills a mob?

Comment: Yeah, but you don't need the tags for that. Just replace the hp2 objective with a new objective that tracks when you killed a specific mob and reset the score right after you've displayed the text.

Comment: Alright. One final issue I'm having is changing the "hp2" objective score. I use . . . {hp2=..5} . . . And this does not display the tellraw message.

Comment: Is hp2 still a dummy objective? if so, you need to change its criteria to minecraft.killed:minecraft.<entity>. To do that, simply remove the objective and create it again using the right criteria.